# Split column to multiple rows based on value pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

I have a record of the following format:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | jack and jill | d |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| z | x | c | v |
| t | y | mom and dad | p |

I need a result set where when I split row 1 and 4

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | IsSplit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | jack | d, | "Y" |
| a | b | jill | d, | "Y" |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | "N" |
| z | x | c | v | "N" |
| t | y | mom | p | "Y" |
| t | y | dad | p | "Y" |

So far I have been able to split the records successfully but unable to determine which of the rows have been split.

```
df = df.withColumn("col3",F.explode(F.split("col3",' and ')))
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rlike` to check whether `' and '` is present in `col3` in order to add the `IsSplit` flag:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'IsSplit', 
    F.when(F.col('col3').rlike(' and '), 'Y').otherwise('N')
).withColumn(
    'col3',
    F.explode(F.split('col3', ' and '))
)

df2.show()
+----+----+----+----+-------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|IsSplit|
+----+----+----+----+-------+
|   a|   b|jack|   d|      Y|
|   a|   b|jill|   d|      Y|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|      N|
|   z|   x|   c|   v|      N|
|   t|   y| mom|   p|      Y|
|   t|   y| dad|   p|      Y|
+----+----+----+----+-------+
```

Comment: what is in col3 it's `["jack", "jill"]`, is there a simpler way to create multiple rows for it?